# Kibana display difficulty

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana

I am new on elasticsearch and I need advice.

I get a JSON via an API that I store in MongoDB then I extract it and insert it into elastisearch when I try to visualize my data in kibana I see this result.

How can I fix this problem?

### my screen discover on kibana

[image: my screen discover on kibana]

Comment: Hi, the question is not clear. please refine your question. what is the issue you experience? I see from the screenshot that the data is visible, so what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to split the json into elasticserach, you can use logstash to do that. There are another ways, but I need to know how you send the information to elasticsearch. Using beats?

Comment: For the moment I send my json with a python script with the elastic API and eventually I want to send it in micro batch. I have to use logstash?

Comment: probably. But, if you don't want to start a logstash just for that, look to filebeat and processors at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html